# Spark RDD persistings every time I call it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I have the following code

```
val dfTransformationToRDD = findLastActiveUsersByEvents(df).withColumn(RedshiftEventEnum.WEIGHT, FunctionsUDFUtil.weightEventUDF(df("type"))).rdd
if(dfTransformationToRDD.getStorageLevel == StorageLevel.NONE){
  println("im persisting ")
  dfTransformationToRDD.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
}
```

I validate rather this RDD has storageLevel so I can know its cached but every time I call this function it always gets into the if block I'm i doing something wrong or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Don't understand the question. The RDD is created in the previous line as a `val` so it cannot have a previous state. What do you expect different?

Comment: thanks for answering so if i make it a var it would not  cache it every time?

Comment: I mean im probably not getting this right if i persist de rdd i dont have to check if is cached? or something? am I suppose to only make .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) and thats it ?

Comment: I still don't get the issue. How can that freshly created RDD already have a persisted flag? What do you call "every time"? Is this within a loop? Or every time you run the job?

Comment: I understand the first time is not gonna be persisted but as you say every time I run that job it keeps getting into that if block which i assume it shouldn't coz it got persisted the first time no?

Comment: The `persisted` flag is a runtime characteristic of the RDD. It will not be "remembered" next time the job runs.

Comment: ye but if i call the same job 3 times on the main method still doest'n seems to be cached, isn't that considered as runtime?

Comment: sorry im new at spark, aprecciate

Comment: You call the job 3 times. Each time, a new RDD called "dfTransformationToRDD" is created. It doesn't know anything about the previous instance. Each time it's persistence level is `NONE`. Imagine that instead of an RDD, you had a list: `val list = List(1,2,3)  val check = if (!list.contains(4)) {println ("list does not contain 4")` ; 4::list} else list` Do you think the result will be different if you run this piece of code 1,2 or 10 times?

Comment: ok, i got it know i got confused by cache like redis, it only persists across execution thanks very much!